# Dynamically Resizing Controls on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I have a winform which can be resized.  I have 4 chart control in the form and sit side by side. When the form is in maximum size, the layout of each chart control is run out. I try to set the anchor style but I got no luck.  How I can make each control equally use the form width?

Normal size winform. The chart control sits side by side.

[image]

Maximum size form, the chart control is not in equal size and not sit side by side

[image]

How can I set the Anchor and make each control in the right position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what a [`SplitContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is for.
It has two panels splitted horizontally or vertically (property [`Orientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.orientation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
The user has then the ability to resize both panels.

Insert a SplitContainer and dock it fully in the parent form. (`Dock = DockStyle.Fill`)
Insert another two SplitContainers in each panel of the top SplitContianer.
Place your charts into the child SplitContainers.

You will find many examples in the web...